# Exactly when can we create a new tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-deletion, specific-question

For [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23388/can-an-astrologer-himself-cast-the-prasna-kundali-for-one-of-his-own-questions), i had created the new tag called horary-astrology. As is evident from the shared wiki link, horary is a distinct branch of astrology. So, for my question it is more apt a tag to use than the regular astrology tag.

But, it was removed.

From [this page](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/tagging):

> As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible, and
>   new users are not allowed to create new tags. Even if you have
>   sufficient reputation, **you should only create new tags when you feel
>   you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that
>   nobody else has asked about before on this site**

So, in this particular case, i am probably asking on a topic which has not been hitherto dealt with here.

Questions:

1.So, how was the tag creation wrong or against the rules and why was it removed?
2. Under what circumstances this particular tag-creation would have been considered as  correct? Or the message given is **we can not create it at all no matter what?**

My points are:

1. Horary is a distinct branch of astrology. So, it demands a new tag for it. When more questions are asked on the subject the users can use it.
2. By removing the tag the signal given is "Don't ask questions on Horary" Or "When we have astrology tag already this new tag is not needed", but this is wrong.
3. If a question is specifically on Horary then the Horary tag obviously should go with it. We can also tag with astrology though, just like some questions are tagged with both Veda and Rig Veda.

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horary_astrology) on Horary:

> Horary astrology **has its own strict system**. The position of and
>   aspects to the moon are of prime importance. The person asking the
>   question, or querent, is represented by the ruler of the sign the
>   first house cusp falls on in the horoscope. **Planetary aspects to the
>   house cusps are considered more important than in other branches of
>   astrology**

From [here](http://www.theastrologyonline.com/horary-astrology/) you can read about traditional Hindu horary by Bhattopala. And, [here](https://www.amazon.in/Prasna-Tantra-Horary-Astrology-Raman/dp/8185674663) is a book on Prasna Tantra (or Horary astrology) by the well-known B.V.Raman. So, the subject has it's own methods and which are distinct from those of Natal astrology.

Comment: Even if the tag isn't allowed, just remove by yourself. Don't let anyone edit you post without your consent.

Comment: I think that the tag is needed. That's y only i created it. But do u think we will forever remain stagnant at one place? we need to expand right? But few are against this expansion. @Tamas. If we are required to incorporate new rules for this expansion to happen then do so. The same applies to milind's recently closed Q. Now, what is really wrong to allow that Q? Is the site losing something or what?

Comment: Then add the tag again after waiting for some answers. It's the we need to expand our branches via tags.

Comment: Somewhat related I had discussed [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/874/277)

Comment: I feel that the tag [horary-astrology] was okay on that post along with the [astrology] tag. Creating a new tag _is_ fine, however, the plagiarized tag excerpt and the wiki shouldn't have been there.

Comment: @Tamas, "Don't let anyone edit you post without your consent", is completely against what Stack Exchange is meant to be. I am afraid that you have not read [How does editing work?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/editing). We are not a dictatorship where only the post owner can edit the question. If you feel that way, then you're certainly in the wrong place.

Comment: the plagiarized tag excerpt and the wiki shouldn't have been there.-- What is this thing? It's new for me. So when we create tag excerpt from wiki we should provide the wiki link as well? Is that what is required? @BhargavRao

Comment: The excerpt should contain a very brief description along with a sentence of when to use it. See [this blog for more info](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/). Also, while writing the tag wiki, you'll need to write it in your own words and provide the link to wiki pages as reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, how was the tag creation wrong or against the rules and why was it removed?

First of all the removal was a simple edit may be to avoid creation of distinct tag from astrology, nothing here is to indicate that you're against the rules etc. So, it sounds you've taken the tag removal very seriously. You could discuss with editor and explain it.

As I discussed [previously](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/874/277) and you've also stated that:

> As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible, and new users are not allowed to create new tags. Even if you have sufficient reputation, you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site

Another thing to note while tagging a question to a new tag is:

[Tagging Don'ts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879/260388):

> Try not to create new tags. If you create a new tag, that tag is guaranteed not to help your question show up on any subscribed RSS feeds or interesting tag lists. Again, the look-ahead prompt can help with this. Odds are it also means you're missing an existing tag for that topic that would more accurately categorize your question.

So, since tags are used to classify the question, it would be useful to use existing popular tag.

Here we already have astrology tag which can cover all the topics related to astrology and Jyotisha i.e Horary as well as Natal Astrology are supposed to be well covered by the astrology tag.

You initially tagged your question with only horary-astrology which can cuase your question ignored or lesser viewd. That's why I think the editor has tagged your question with astrology tag.

Now, it would be better to create a tag if  community can get benefit of it i.e if there are well scope of  getting  question on that topic. Here astrology is a popular tag and that would also work for your question.

Anyway, if you want the horary-astrology tag, I recommend to use astrology tag along with it. As it's suggested:

[Effective Tags - Bring more attention to your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879/260388)

> At a minimum, try to include at least one very broad tag (e.g., java or c#) and one other tag to narrow the topic down within that broader category (e.g., strings or garbage-collection).

So, if you feel that astrology tag would work well for your question, no need to create separate tag for horary-astrology and if you feel the horary-astrology tag would be beneficial to the community, no problem with it's creation, just keep in mind to tag atleast one broader tag i.e astrology alongwith horary-astrology

Comment: if you want the horary-astrology tag, I recommend to use astrology tag along with it. As it's suggested:-- I have already said that it is quite correct to do so in my Q.

Comment: @Rickross well, you used only horary-astrology tag, right? and editor might thought that "astrology would work well and there are no more case of horary questions"

Comment: According to ur logic he should have simply added astrology tag with out doing any other thing. And if that had happened, then i would not be posting here.

Comment: @Rickross well, as I said you took the tag removal very seriously, this way we will have frequent meta questions!

Comment: Well ur statements are not logical, "you have taken things seriously"- these are not talks that are based on "rules". Here i am bothered about rules (because here everyone talks based on rules). Is there any harm in meta being more active? Anyways, i will ask always when i have any questions.

Comment: @Rickross ok. No problem. I am just saying that creative and usefulQ/A on meta can make policy more clear

Comment: BTW according to ur answer i can rollback anytime and add astrology tag along with?

Comment: @Rickross astrology is already added, now you need to just add horary-astrology.

Comment: @Rickross Yes. You can use astrology as broad tag and horary-astrology as narrow tag.

Comment: Yes that's right. OK

Comment: @Pandya You may be surprised, but some people take all edits and closing of questions seriously. This can be very demoralizing to new users. I know that making tags is more advanced, but it can still be upsetting. Wikipedia suffers this same problem. There is so much bureaucracy for a new person who just wants to learn something about a specific topic. The point being that communication is key and will lead to more user interaction as well as better educating the community as to the mechanisms and rules. One nice thing is that this is much less of a problem in Hinduism.SE than elsewhere.