# First my flags for irrelevant comments get rejected and then a moderator himself deletes the same comments

Tags: support, moderators, comments, flagging

I had flagged 3 comments that were posted under my question [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/exactly-when-can-we-create-a-new-tag). The comments were absolutely not related to my question.

The flags were rejected. But then the same comments were deleted some time later by a moderator himself. (I can say that the comments were not self deleted because the user's last activity was some 6 hrs ago and the deletion of comments occurred around 3 hrs ago).

I want to know the reason as to why this has happened.

Comment: May be one moderator thought that comments should not be deleted hence rejected ur flag and another thought in opposite way and deleted them...

Comment: Whether that is the case or not we will get to know soon. @YDS

Comment: Sometimes wrong flags and wrong comments also cause the flag rejection and this meta question is about deletion of rude comments!!!.

Comment: this meta question is about deletion of rude comments!!!-- How do u know? It's only known to me which comments i had flagged and the mods also know it. FYI, the comments that i had flagged are not at all rude but they were absolutely irrelevant to my post.

Comment: If you don't put @Sarvabhouma, it doesn't notify me. I just guessed which comments they are because in one of the comments you said they were obsolete but they are not really. They were saying what is on-topic on meta. It could be helpful to others which comments you were talking about. There were very rude comments under your post and I flagged them and the flags were marked helpful. So, the other comments which are replies to deleted rude comments will also be deleted. So, the deletion doesn't surprise me.  So, I believe you flagged wrong comments and chose wrong reason.