# Should there be a tag called "minutiae" or "trivia" for questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

For example - the names of the 101 clans of yadavas.

Comment: for creating tags u don't need to ask anyone.. i think u even created a tag called "authentic" :D

Comment: @Rickross NO, it is not like that. When we create a new tag, there is a banner showing raise on meta. So, there should be a discussion. Tags should be useful and there should not be new tags for each and every question. They should be only created when necessary.

Comment: @@Sk You can see my question [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/exactly-when-can-we-create-a-new-tag). I am asking the same thing, but there the tag i had created was destroyed..so u can create a tag when u feel it's needed.. no need for asking for approval/permission..

Comment: Minutiae are minor details of negligible importance to the story at hand. Importance is then left up to the judgement whoever is adding a tag. On the other hand, `minor-details`, IMO, removes the judgmental factor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes I agree, I think there should be a tag for such questions. I have found many questions here which are utterly useless from religious point of view. E.g, how many names are there for Karna, What was the name of a particular chariot, what was the name of conch shells of pandavas or kauravs etc. Like for philosophical questions a separate tag `philosophy` is maintained then why not to maintain a tag for such highly insignificant questions?

Comment: Questions which are utterly useless for you could be useful for others. Many people are interested in this type of questions also. There is no need of a new tag.Questions utterly useless are off-topic questions. There are already apt tags. It becomes a meta tag if created.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma so better to have a poll and see how many people think such questions useless or not

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Stack Exchange is not for polls. It is stories and the questions like these most of the people (not this site) are interested. Look at the views they have than the philosophies. Only some people talk about philosophy and the like. Calling some questions useless and insignificant is not good for the site and leads to partiality in the site. The site should have all types of questions. When it comes to tag creation, tagging them as trivial is like a stamp like "useless" as per this answer. That is why I disagree with the suggestion.

Comment: 'what was the name of conch shells of pandavas' - luckily, no has asked yet where are those shells now...which museum...and birth stories of those shells!!!

Comment: @sv. Don't give new ideas now for birth stories now. :)