# Is it recommended to open a tag for considerable persons in scriptures?

Tags: discussion, tags

Sanathan dharma contains plenty of scriptures and scriptures contain plenty of persons.

Some are very significant: Rama, Krishna, Pandavas, lakshmana, Nala etc., Some may be considerable: Dhaumya,  Maarecha etc.,

Is it recommended to create new tags for considerable persons?

Comment: Related: [Exactly when can we create a new tag?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1107/277)